# UTF8 text on OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, utf-8, bidi

I am trying to draw a UTF8 text on a `cv::Mat`. OpenCV does not support UTF8 (somehow [`cv::freetype::FreeType2`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html) is not included in my OpenCV package), so the idea is to:

1. Acquire and process image in OpenCV (`imencode`);
2. Convert data to JPEG;
3. Load data in a third party library API, draw text using that API;
4. Encode back image to JPEG;
5. Load JPEG image into OpenCV (`imdecode`)

I am looking for a reasonably small image manipulation library that supports drawing text on JPEG (or PNG) in-memory data, being aware of [Unicode BiDi](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics) and [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: I don't know about `bidi` but I have printed text on Jpeg using [libgd](https://libgd.github.io/).

Comment: Perhaps these might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323096/puttext-for-utf-8-characters-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519373/opencv-puttext-utf-8-characters